# CodeDom method body definition

Tags: c#, methods, codedom

I would like to understand which is the cleanest way to generate class with Code Dom, in particular i am interestd in method body generation.

I have see MSDN example (first between google's results), but method body generation seems to me a little complicatied and it only consists in few simple instructions (i would like to write some lambda instead).

Answer (score 0):

CodedDom allows you to write any code you wish for with [CodeSnippetStatement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.codesnippetstatement%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). you can check the code example in the link.

not everything is supported in CodeDom , but if your purpose is to create code on run time, you should read about [Expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

P.S: microsoft no longer support CodeDom

Comment: No i would generate some kind of C# project template (with a lot of customization) written by my application.
Ps : i have read this article https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404245%28v=vs.110%29.aspx but method body generation seem very unreadeable to me and i try to find better way to do that.

Comment: if you talked about addMethod function, it writes 
`string.formt("the object width: {0} heigth:{1}, area:{2},Width, heigth,Area);`

it create a reference for each property and combine it in a string format

Comment: So a shortest whay to do so is to use directly string format with fragment of code ?

Comment: exacly, if you use snippet it will takes you one row